# Angular / How to make sure that an incomplete server model won't break ngModel?

Tags: angular

The value of the following control is bound to an employee object. How can I make sure that this won't break if the server won't return person on employee?

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="employee-name" [(ngModel)]="employee.person.details.name" required>
```

Is there a way that the missing object path get's created on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model class for your employee and initiate it with blank person details name, then you instantiate your employee attribute with that model class

```
export class YourClass {

  employee: Employee = new Employee(); //default constructor
  ...
  service.getEmployee().subscribe((res) => this.employee = new Employee(res)); //custom constructor
  ...

}
```

Comment: Would that not be a casting? res <Employee>res?

Comment: @TrevorHector yeah it can be

Answer (score 0):

In going back and actually looking at my code :-) ... I see that I have an initialize method that returns an initialized object for this purpose:

```
initializeProduct(): IProduct {
    // Return an initialized object
    return {
        id: 0,
        productName: null,
        productCode: null,
        category: null,
        tags: [],
        releaseDate: null,
        price: null,
        description: null,
        starRating: null,
        imageUrl: null
    };
}
```

Yours would need to be more complex because it has so more levels of child objects. But you could do something similar. I use this when creating a "new" entry to ensure that I don't see "undefined" errors.